# problems inheriting from a c++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

So I'm trying to work out how inheritance works when templates are in the mix. Most compilers really don't seem to have this figured out yet, so I'm having a little syntax difficulty. All the weird includes in SkipNode.h are from trying to get eclipse to stop yelling at me. I'm getting a syntax error when trying to declare the constructor in SkipNode.h, so any help here would be useful.

Here is node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_

template<class T>
class Node
{
public:

    Node(Node<T>* next, Node<T>* prev, T item);

    virtual ~Node();

    Node* getPrev() { return prev;};

    Node* getNext() { return next;};

    Node* getItem() { return item;};

    void setItem(T item){Node<T>::item = item;};

    void setNext(Node* next){Node<T>::next = next;};

    void setPrev(Node* prev){Node<T>::prev = prev;};
private:
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    T item;
};
```

Here is SkipNode.h, where skipnode inherits from Node.

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "Node.cpp"
#include "SkipNode.h"
#include "SkipNode.cpp"

template <class T>
class SkipNode: public Node
{
public:
    SkipNode(Node<T>* next, Node<T>* prev, Node<T>* child, T item) : Node(next, prev, item);

    virtual ~SkipNode();

    Node* getChild(){return child;};

    void setChild(Node* child){SkipNode::child = child;};

private:
    Node *child;
};

#endif /* SKIPNODE_H_ */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Node` is a template, you should pass in template parameter

```
template <class T>
class SkipNode: public Node<T>
//                         ^^^
```

Also you need to provide `SkipNode` constructor definition as you have provided `member iniatilizer list`.

update:

```
SkipNode(Node<T>* next, Node<T>* prev, Node<T>* child, T item) 
: Node(next, prev, item);
```

To:

```
SkipNode(Node<T>* next, Node<T>* prev, Node<T>* child, T item)
: Node(next, prev, item)
{
}
```

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested, but it still doesn't like something here.. I had already tried these changes without any luck

Comment: It will be helpful if you post real error message. you may have more errors.

Comment: Ah ok, so I have to define the constructor in the header file in this case?

Comment: Yeah it's happy now. But how do I do this such that the signature is in the header file, and I can have my definition in the CPP file?

Comment: template is a bit different, you may want to provide definition in header instead.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing an `#endif` in node.h and you need to provide the template parameter to your base class:

```
template <class T>
class SkipNode : public Node< T >
....
```

This level of indirection exists to allow inheritance from a template class by a class that has different (or zero) template parameters. For instance:

```
class Foo : public Node< int >
```